# Field 'sid' doesn't have a default value

Tags: joomla-4.x

Only new to Joomla- I need to add a new link to this list of links. As you can see in the picture it's only a link with a description but when trying to save it appears with "Save failed with the following error: Field 'sid' doesn't have a default value". No images are trying to be uploaded or selected. I have checked other links in the list and they are set up the same way. It will let me edit a link of an existing link but not create a new one.
Any hits or suggestions?

[image: Field 'sid' doesn't have a default value]

Comment: Which web links component are you using? "Weblinks" by "Joomla Official Extensions"? 
 https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/weblinks/

Comment: I went into manage extensions and from what I can tell it's Web Links by Joomla! Project.

Comment: There is no `sid` column in Joomla core, nor in Weblinks extension. If you have access to database, inspect `#__weblinks` table to see if it had `sid` column added to it. If not, then it must be some 3rd party plugin that runs when saving content.